# Are questions about site monitoring appropriate for this site?

Tags: discussion

I've flagged [Keep a check on 404s](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/29468/keep-a-check-on-404s?noredirect=1#comment35145_29468) for moderator attention, but I can't decide myself it if's appropriate for SQA or not.  So, meta.  Basically, the person wants to know how best to long-term monitor a Web site for availability/errors.  To me, that's not a test question.  That would totally be a test question if it was about how to monitor a Web site so I can detect problems when I'm testing it, but not "How can I notify someone if my production site goes down?"  The fact that the QA department in their organization is irrelevant; it's not being done as part of a test/QA activity.

https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/920/how-to-create-a-centralised-dashboard-to-monitor-multiple-cloud-amazon-and-goog

is probably an answer to the question, or at least a starting point.

Comment: I've marked the flag as "helpful" initially but then could not decide if it is appropriate to be closed - it is still related to testing but is also related to devops/monitoring and overall tooling around testing a site for dead links. We've been also closing a lot recently and seeing that the OP is an active user with sqa site history and defending the question contributed to the decision to not close. Thanks.

Comment: Understood, and, as I said, it's partly a philosophical question.  Also a site question about whether we want to answer the same question in multiple places on multiple stackexchanges, or just have a canonical answer in one place.

Comment: I'm also torn on this one. Long-term monitoring for site failures/errors is a network management/devops activity, but it's not rare for test teams to find themselves pushed into activities that aren't, strictly speaking, test activities.

Comment: It is clearly not a test activity. The question I believe is "Is it a QA activity?", or more succinctly, "Is it a QA activity we support on this site?"

Comment: In my opinion it's definitely a QA question and something I do fairly regular for the company I work at. In the end I think that the difference between Dev Ops and QA engineering is pretty much only semantics. The availability of a  system is pretty much the highest priority for product quality (you can have the best app on the face of the planet, if no one can access it it's crap) and if you host for a costumer it's one of you companies quality concerns to assure that the app stays online.

Comment: @KevinMcKenzie I understand the desire to have a canonical answer in one place, but I don't think that's what we want to optimize for.  There will always be ambiguity about where to put some kinds of questions.  If we try to optimize for "each question belongs in at most one place", some people won't bother to ask questions at all, even when they're reasonable questions.

Answer (score 3):

No, site monitoring questions aren't appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, site monitoring problems are appropriate.